# Add and Print new Nodes

Tags: java

I was working on a program to add nodes to a list, but I seem to be doing something wrong...

My java program has three Classes; Demo, Lista and Node

Class Node:

```
public class Node {
    
    private int num;
    private Node tail;
    private Node head; 

    public Node (int num, Node head, Node tail) {
        this.num = num;
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
}
```

Class Lista:

```
public class Lista {
    
    private Node nil;
    
    public Lista () {
        nil = null;
    }
    
    public void add (int num) {
        Node newNode = new Node(num, head, tail);
        
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    public void display () {
        Node current = head;
        
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.num);
        }
    }
}
```

Class Demo:

```
public class Demo {
    
    public static void main ( String [] args) {
        Lista lista = new Lista();
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(9);
        lista.add(7);
        lista.display();
    }
}
```

Demo class is to add the different nodes to the list "lista". Class Node has num, head which is the next one and tail which is the previous one. How can I go about getting Class Lista to be able to use head and tail from Class Node? And if it is possible would this code work when running Demo? What should I change/modify to get this to work?

Comment: In your `while` loop you should traverse your linked list, but you don't. You are staying on a single place and don't moving forward in your linked list. Use debugger and go step by step to view the situation clearly.

Comment: adding something like current = current.head after the System.out.print?

Comment: What are head and tail in Lista? You are not defining them; can you please add that part of the code, also?

Comment: head and tail and the private Node in Class Node. I just wasn't sure how to access those values on Lista... or if it is even possible to do so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to modify your code something like this:

EDIT - This is a doubly-linked list implementation.

```
class Node {
    int num;
    Node prev;
    Node next;

    Node(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    Node(int num, Node prev, Node next) {
        this.num = num;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }

    void setPrev(Node prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}


class Lista {
    Node root;
    Node endNode;

    public void add(int num) {
        Node n = new Node(num);

        if (root == null) {
            root = n;
        } else {
            n.setPrev(endNode);
            endNode.setNext(n);
        }
        endNode = n;
    }

    public void display() {
        Node iterateeNode = root;

        while (iterateeNode != null) {
            System.out.print(iterateeNode.num + " ");
            iterateeNode = iterateeNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the function/purpose of root and endNode in Lista?

Comment: These are the end nodes of a doubly linked list where the `root` is the end node from left (beginning) and the `endNode` is the end node from the right (end of the list).

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is technically not correct. For a (single) Linked List, all your `Lista` need is a single (head) node. Additionally, the `Node` class needs a single (next) Node field.

The following is a potential implementation of Node:

```
public class Node {
    
  private Node next;
  private int value;

  public Node(int value) {
      this.value = value;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
      return next != null;
  }
  
  public Node next() {
    return next;
  }
  
  public void add(Node node) {
    if (next == null) {
        next = node;
    } else {
        Node temp = next;
        while (temp != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp = node;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }
}
```

The `add()` method will insert the new node in `next` if it is null. Otherwise, it will traverse the nodes until it finds the tail node (the one where `next` is null).

The `Lista` has only the first element in the list (head node).

```
public class Lista {
    private Node head;
    
    public void add(Node node) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.hasNext()) {
                temp = temp.next();
            }
            temp.add(node);
        }
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

When the `add()` function in the list is called, it will either add the new node as the head (if the list doesn't have one already) or rely on the already added nodes to figure out where the end of the list is in order to insert the new node.

Lastly, to display the list, just override the `toString()` method in node and add the "toString" value to a string buffer and send the concatenated string value to the console similar to the the code below.

```
public void display() {
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder("[");
    buff.append(head);
    if (head != null) {
        Node next = head.next();
        buff.append(",");
        while (next != null) {
            buff.append(next);
            next = next.next();
            buff.append(",");
        }
    }
    buff.append("]");
    int idx = buff.lastIndexOf(",");
    buff.replace(idx, idx+1, "");
    System.out.println(buff.toString());
}
```

Executing the following displays `[3,9,7]` as expected.

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main ( String [] args) {
      Lista lista = new Lista();
      lista.add(new Node(3));
      lista.add(new Node(9));
      lista.add(new Node(7));
      lista.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: For this task as it has been described, a singly linked list is enough, and the code is working correctly. But it seems like there's a bit of redundancy with these two `add()` methods, or I'm missing something? I mean, both methods are capable of iterating over the list. The `else` part of the `add()` in the node is not utilized (`add()` from the list delegates the job to `add()` in the node when `next` is `null`), and fills like there's a bug in this unused block of code.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko There is no redundancy in this particular example. This is the "classic" academic implementation of a singly linked list. `Lista` is the list class. You `add()` elements to the list. Your API should expose ONLY this method. `Node` should be hidden from clients other than `Lista`. Basically, `Node` implementation should not be public and all the interactions needed should be done thru the list class. Then, the rest of my explanation applies: If the list already has a head element, it will delegate down to the `Node` class to figure out adding the next element at the end...

Comment: ... For the `Node` to be private, the `Lista` method should only accept _values_ to be added and not nodes directly (because the client should know nothing about "nodes." Is that clearer now?

Comment: The only thing I see might be needed is a way to prevent the `add()` function to take a `null` value.

Comment: *For the Node to be private, the Lista method should only accept values to be added and not nodes directly (because the client should know nothing about "nodes."* - yes, that's clear.

Comment: I was asking about the `else` block in nodes's `add()` method. There's a local variable `Node temp = next;`, when control breaks out of the loop `temp` is `null` and then it's being assigned with the node passed as argument `temp = node;` - so we are just reassigning the local variable. I'm not quite getting this part. Look that what I mean https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t3t . I don't understand how it can affect the last node?

Comment: I've changed this snippet (original lines were commented out) https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t3z now, in my understanding when `next != null` and we are hitting else case it would traverse the list and append the given node to the very last node.